# How to create dynamic columns in a pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables and I want to pivot a table and the number of columns in the pivot table should be based on how many columns I want.

This is the first table

**DefectiveTableList**

```
SysID  |    DefectClassificationName  | CreatedAt
-------|------------------------------|-------------
    4  |    Wrong Color               | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
    5  |    Paper Is Thin             | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
    6  |    Misaligned Print          | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
    7  |    Defective Device          | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
    8  |    Delamination              | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
    9  |    Burned Lamination         | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
   10  |    Cracked Box               | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
   11  |    Faded Color               | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
   12  |    Overlapping               | 2022-08-26 16:31:20.470
```

And this is the second table

**SchoolDetail**

```
ID  |   SchoolHeaderID | DefectClassification | Sample | Score
----|------------------|----------------------|--------|-------
   1|                 1| Overlapping          |       0|    3.0
   2|                 1| Delamination         |       0|    2.0
   5|                 1| Cracked Box          |       0|    1.5
   8|                 1| Wrong Color          |       1|    3.0
  13|                 3| Wrong Color          |       0|    3.0
  14|                 3| Burned Lamination    |       0|    1.0
  17|                 3| Misaligned Print     |       2|    1.5
  20|                 3| Paper Is Thin        |      10|    2.0
  23|                 3| Overlapping          |      11|    1.0
```

Now what I want is to get the maximum value in the sample column based on `schoolHeaderID` and used it to display a number of columns in the pivot table.

For example, I want to display the result in `SchoolHeaderID=3`, so this should be the query:

```
Declare @NoOfCol as int 
SELECT @NoOfCol=MAX(Sample) FROM SchoolDetail WHERE SchoolHeaderID=3
```

The result should be 11 and the number of columns should be 12 starting from 0. The rows should be the `DefectClassificationName` in **DefectiveTableList** and the `Score` is based on what sample and what defect.

The result should be like this:

```
DefectClassificationName |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |  10 |  11 
-------------------------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|-----|-----
Wrong Color              | 3.0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Paper Is Thin            |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|  2.0| NULL
Misaligned Print         |NULL|NULL| 1.5|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Defective Device         |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Delamination             |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Burned Lamination        | 1.0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Cracked Box              |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Faded Color              |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL
Overlapping              |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| NULL|  1.0
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server (`select @@version`)? What is the max number allowed in `Sample`? Is `SchoolHeaderID + DefectClassification` guaranteed to be unique? What happens if they are not, do you want sum, avg, max, ...?

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in my answer, you say you need the defect name from the list table, but why? You could drop that table and still have all the information you need to satisfy the query, because (for some reason) you're repeating those strings in the detail table - so there's no reason to join to the list table to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you want is, for example:

```
SELECT dtl.DefectClassificationName,
 [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]
FROM dbo.DefectiveTableList AS dtl
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM dbo.SchoolDetail
  PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN (
    [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]
  )
  ) AS p WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @sh
) AS sd ON dtl.DefectClassificationName = sd.DefectClassification;
```

To get there, we can first pull the `MAX(Sample)`, use a recursive CTE to build a comma-separated list of column names, inject those into the larger query, and then use `sp_executesql`.

```
DECLARE @SchoolHeaderID int = 3;

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @maxCol int = (SELECT MAX(Sample) 
    FROM dbo.SchoolDetail 
    WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @SchoolHeaderID);

WITH recursiveCTE(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT num+1 
  FROM recursiveCTE WHERE num < @maxCol
)
SELECT @cols += CONCAT(N',', QUOTENAME(num)) 
  FROM recursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT 
  dtl.DefectClassificationName' + @cols + N'
FROM dbo.DefectiveTableList AS dtl
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM dbo.SchoolDetail
  PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN ('
   + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N'') + N'
  )) AS p
  WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @sh
) AS sd
ON dtl.DefectClassificationName = sd.DefectClassification;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@sh int', @sh = @SchoolHeaderID;
```

Here's [an example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5JJ5Z10Z).

On the other hand, after you [changed the sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/HN6_laPi) to make it clear that `SchoolHeaderID + DefectClassification` was in fact not unique, the query you need is slightly different (you need to aggregate *after* joining):

```
DECLARE @sh int = 1;

WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT dtl.DefectClassificationName, sd.Score, sd.Sample
  FROM dbo.DefectiveTableList AS dtl
  INNER JOIN dbo.SchoolDetail AS sd
    ON dtl.DefectClassificationName = sd.DefectClassification
  WHERE sd.SchoolHeaderID = @sh
)
SELECT DefectClassificationName, [0],[1]
  FROM d PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN ([0],[1])) AS p;
```

And you would build this in much the same way ([example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fQKB-4iF)):

```
DECLARE @SchoolHeaderID int = 1;

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @maxCol int = (SELECT MAX(Sample) 
    FROM dbo.SchoolDetail 
    WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @SchoolHeaderID);

WITH recursiveCTE(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT num+1 
  FROM recursiveCTE WHERE num < @maxCol
)
SELECT @cols += CONCAT(N',', QUOTENAME(num)) 
  FROM recursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT dtl.DefectClassificationName, sd.Score, sd.Sample
  FROM dbo.DefectiveTableList AS dtl
  INNER JOIN dbo.SchoolDetail AS sd
    ON dtl.DefectClassificationName = sd.DefectClassification
  WHERE sd.SchoolHeaderID = @sh
)
SELECT DefectClassificationName' + @cols + N'
  FROM d PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN ('
  + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N'') + N')) AS p;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@sh int', @sh = @SchoolHeaderID;
```

That all said, why is the join to `DefectiveTableList` even necessary? If your `Detail` table contained the `ID` values that would make sense, but you don't have a very normalized design here, as you've repeated the strings in the detail table, which makes the join unnecessary. Just think: what are you *actually getting* from the other table? If there are other details we don't know, okay, but in the present state it feels like the query could be much simpler:

```
DECLARE @sh int = 1;

WITH d AS
(
  SELECT DefectClassification, Score, Sample
  FROM dbo.SchoolDetail AS sd
  WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @sh
)
SELECT DefectClassificationName = DefectClassification,
  [0],[1] FROM d
  PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN ([0],[1])) AS p;
```

And again we would generate it the same way ([example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zimSu7lP)):

```
DECLARE @SchoolHeaderID int = 1;

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @maxCol int = (SELECT MAX(Sample) 
    FROM dbo.SchoolDetail 
    WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @SchoolHeaderID);

WITH recursiveCTE(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT num+1 
  FROM recursiveCTE WHERE num < @maxCol
)
SELECT @cols += CONCAT(N',', QUOTENAME(num)) 
  FROM recursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'WITH d AS
(
  SELECT DefectClassification, Score, Sample
  FROM dbo.SchoolDetail AS sd
  WHERE SchoolHeaderID = @sh
)
SELECT DefectClassificationName = DefectClassification
  ' + @cols + N'
  FROM d PIVOT (MAX(Score) FOR Sample IN ('
  + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N'') + N')) AS p;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@sh int', @sh = @SchoolHeaderID;
```

Note that `MAXRECURSION` is only necessary if `Sample` can be greater than 100 (and if it can be greater than 32,767, you will have other problems generating that many columns anyway). And `STRING_AGG()` could be used instead of `+=` concatenation on SQL Server 2017+.

Comment: I tried your code but the problem is that the score in each sample is displayed in different rows whenever the defect classification is the same.  It should be Wrong Image Color - 3.0 - 3.0. Not Wrong Image Color - 3.0,  Wrong Image Color - 3.0. Please see this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/HN6_laPi

Comment: This answer seem to work fine, @Rak . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4rcy_q6P) You appear to have changed the solution here.

Comment: Not really. What I want is that whenever the sample has the same defect, it should be in the same row. Not in different rows, so it should be like this: Wrong Image Color - 3.0 - 3.0. Not Wrong Image Color - 3.0, Wrong Image Color - 3.0

Comment: @Rak You changed the sample data for row 5, ID 13, you moved it from SchoolHeaderID 3 to SchoolHeaderID 1. Please sort out your sample data and expected outcome, and include expected outcome for ID 1 if you’re going to change the source data after the fact. This is exactly why, by the way, I asked if SchoolHeaderID + DefectClassification were unique. The sample data in the question looks that way, but you changed it in your fiddle for some reason, and it’s unfair to do that to people.

Comment: There's only 1 wrong color row in that [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4rcy_q6P) @Rak . The Fiddle you supplied doesn't use the SQL from the answer here.

Comment: @Rak I've made adjustments based on the new information. In the future, please don't quietly sabotage the original sample data and then complain that the solution doesn't work. It worked perfectly fine on the original sample data.